# How do I carry a mouse with me without damaging the middle mouse button or other buttons?

Tags: mouse, mouse-buttons, transporting

As a student, I need to carry a mouse with my laptop, but I often end up busting up mice within a year because the middle mouse button gets pressed on hard enough in my backpack to damage it in short order. I've gone through some good Logitech and Microsoft mice as a result of this, and I'm not a fan of the Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse.

How do I travel with a mouse without risking this kind of damage?

(Note that answers may require recommending hardware, but keep in mind this is not meant to be a hardware or shopping recommendation question and solutions need not recommend any product.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a hard case. A cheap and ugly yet effective solution would be a plastic soap box. Shockingly, Google indicates mouse specific hard cases exist. Maybe add some padding if you must.

Another solution might be to get a flexible mousepad, and roll up your mouse in the mousepad when you carry it

Comment: Soap boxes are great, you can use them for decks of cards too!

Answer (score 1):

I never thought of this, but as suggested by Journeyman Geek, a hard case is the answer.

The [Pelican 1040](http://www.pelican.com/cases_detail.php?Case=1040), at 6.5" x 3.87" x 1.75" inside (LWD), seems to be just the right fit for the larger gaming mice I use (but may be a bit tight; some very large mice, such as the ROCCAT Tyon with its protruding Dorsal Fin-Switch, may require the [1060](http://www.pelican.com/cases_detail.php?Case=1060)). For smaller travel mice, the [1010](http://www.pelican.com/cases_detail.php?Case=1010) or [1020](http://www.pelican.com/cases_detail.php?Case=1020) would be ideal. The matching 10x2 Pick 'N' Pluck foam insert should let me get just the right fit.

They're a tad bulky, but they provide the level of protection I need.

[image: Pelican 1040 case]

[image: ROCCAT Tyon in Pelican 1060 case]